# Manage Cookie with Android Application

Tags: android, cookies

Please,
Can I manage (create and use) Cookies with Android Application? If yes, How ?
Thank you.

Comment: You can use HTTPCokies. Post some code so that we can help you. Refer to this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpCookie.html and this http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpCookie.html

Comment: Hello ISPN have you resolved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Till today there are no google verified apps are available to view or edit cookies in android. Each of your browsers in your android mobile will be storing their cookies in their own specific folders by the extension **sqlite**.